# Getting below error on running PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am using one PowerShell script to download content (a zip file) from a website which requires credentials to get authenticated for the website. Also, have used proxy and proxy credentials since it is an authenticated proxy. I am getting an error which I have pasted below.

I have tried giving the proxy and proxy credentials but no luck. 
I have bypassed the execution policy using `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`. 
When I try accessing the website from my browser then I am able to access the zip file.

Please find the code snippet below:

```bsh
#Path to Save data
$tipath = "C:\Somepath"
$localpath = "\somefile.zip"
$timepath = "\Zip_file.txt"
$unzippath = "\Someotherpath"
$storepath = $tipath + $localpath
$remotefilepath = $tipath + $timepath
$unzipfolder = $tipath + $unzippath

#   Create Folder If Not Exists #
$FolderToCreate = $tipath
if (!(Test-Path $FolderToCreate -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $FolderToCreate
}

#Downloading File #
$username = "username"
$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

$secPasswd = "password123" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("domain\user", $secPasswd)

# get remote file info
Invoke-WebRequest -Proxy "http://x.x.x.x:8080" -ProxyCredential $myCreds -Uri "https://somewebsite/checksum.txt" -OutFile $remotefilepath -Credential $cred
$remotefile = Get-Content -Path $remotefilepath
Write-Host Remote File Hash : $remotefile

# if the file exists already
if (Test-Path $storepath) {
    # get local file info
    $localfile = (Get-FileHash $storepath -Algorithm SHA256).Hash
    Write-Host Local File Hash : $localfile

    # if the remote file is newer than the local file
    if ($remotefile -ne $localfile) {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Proxy "http://x.x.x.x:8080" -ProxyCredential $myCreds -Uri "https://somewebsite/checksum.txt" -OutFile $remotefilepath -Credential $cred
        Invoke-WebRequest -Proxy "http://x.x.x.x:8080" -ProxyCredential $myCreds -Uri "https://somewebsite/somezipfile.zip" -OutFile $storepath -Credential $cred
```

This code should check the hash and download directly download the zip file from the website and unzip it.
If it can download in the zip file then the later part I can troubleshoot.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mypowershell.ps1
powershell : Invoke-WebRequest :     .?? ??? ?????? ???????? ??? ????? ?????
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mypowershell.p ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invoke-WebReque...??? ????? ?????:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

The site you are trying to access contains content that is prohibited.
If you believe the website you are trying to access does not contain any such
content, please click here.
```

Above is the error I am getting.

Comment: Are you behind company firewall?

Comment: You should really attempt to share the code, simply remove the sensitive information e.g usernames/passwords/websites and so on - it'll allow us to help in a more efficient manner.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers : Thanks for your reply. Yes we are behind firewall. My question is if firewall is blocking the traffic then how are we able to access the website and download the content from browser?

Comment: @Matthew - Have updated the question with code snippet. Please help.

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal - do you provide credentials when downloading the file using your browser? I'd try burpsuite or Wireshark to capture what actuall gets send and try to mimic that with Powershell. Could be something as bening as the user agent.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - While downloading the file using browser I didn't entered the credentials. I believe it will take it from the script itself. Still I will try by removing  stored credentials and remove credentials from the script and will check and update you.